# UITabBarItems disappear when setting new frame of UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

In my application when the contact tab is clicked (Middle button), I want to move the UITabBar up from the bottom of the screen and display a view below it.

However when I move the UITabBar up with the following code, the UITabBarItems disappear:

```
- (void)moveTabBarUpwards
{
    [self.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    //[self.tabBar.items[0] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]
[image]

Even though the tabs disappear, the toolbar still functions correctly in the new position. Not sure why this is happening.

**Edit**

If I move the tab bar right to the top then the UITabBarItems remain in the same place. If I move the y to say 10 I get the following (as you can see, the UITabBarItems are still visible but have move down slightly):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that altering iOS' standard UI elements frames directly is a good point at all. Same goes here for `UINavigationBar` for example.

I'd advise you to create your own model of a `UIView` with `UIButtons` and a parent view controller with child VCs as tabs. This way, you'll be 100% safe in future iOS releases, because no one beside Apple really knows which way any given component of iOS is going to go.

Comment: Thanks for the advice SergiusGee. I have gone with creating a view controller that has a container view to house the tab bar selection views. Then I have a view with at the bottom with buttons on for the tab bar itself.

Comment: @pls Glad to be of help!